# which one has better performance to load views

Tags: views

When I want to print my views block result(or views) in my `tpl` files,I have several ways,

[views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)

[views_get_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7)

[module_invoke](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7) for block ( I means something like `$block = module_invoke('views', 'block', 'view', 'map-block_1');` )

which one is better and has better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

views_embed_view is just a wrapper for views_get_view:

```
function views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default') {
  $args = func_get_args();
  array_shift($args); // remove $name
  if (count($args)) {
    array_shift($args); // remove $display_id
  }

  $view = views_get_view($name);
  if (!$view || !$view->access($display_id)) {
    return;
  }

  return $view->preview($display_id, $args);
}
```

So how would you set dynamic arguments on views_embed_view? With views_get_view you can at least do this:

```
  $view = views_get_view($view_name);
  if (!$view || !$view->access($display_id)) {
    return;
  }
  $view->set_display($display_id);
  $view->set_arguments($variables);
  $view->pre_execute();
  $view->execute();
  return $view->render();
```

module_invoke for block is too roundabout and limited for my liking. Why limit yourself to a block when you can choose from any display available?

views_block_view contains this snippet:

```
if ($view = views_get_view($name)) {
```

So it also uses Views_get_view.

Performance-wise I reckon the differences are negligible.

So, IMO, views_get_view wins.